# How do I run script on all databases in sql server (2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I modify the following script so that it runs on all the database in my sql server:

```
use master
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP SQLAlwaysonGroup REMOVE DATABASE [AlbumsTestk4L7]
alter database [AlbumsTestk4L7] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
use [AlbumsTestk4L7]
DBCC SHRINKFILE ([AlbumsTestk4L7_Log], 0);
--ALTER DATABASE [AlbumsTestk4L7_Log] MODIFY FILE (NAME = [AlbumsTestk4L7_Log] ,SIZE = 200MB, FILEGROWTH = 10MB, MAXSIZE=1000MB)
ALTER DATABASE [AlbumsTestk4L7] SET RECOVERY FULL
BACKUP DATABASE [AlbumsTestk4L7] TO DISK = 'NUL'
use master;
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP SQLAlwaysonGroup ADD DATABASE [AlbumsTestk4L7]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use sp_msforeachdb and replace the database name in your script with a question mark.

Comment: Thanks. how would you handle DBCC SHRINKFILE ([AlbumsTestk4L7_Log], 0); as far as using "?"

Comment: is there a way to automatically get log file name?